# Trying to run a Library and it starts succesful and then the web page displays the following error. Specific error detected by ANCM:

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2

HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies
Common solutions to this issue:
The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
Specific error detected by ANCM:
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found. - The following frameworks were found: 2.1.12 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 2.1.13 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 2.1.14 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 3.1.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 3.1.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK. The specified framework can be found at: - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=2.2.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028526

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2 .NET Core 2.2 is end of life. Switch to a supported version please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the stack trace, download .Net Core SDK 2.2. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2